Istio gateway Canary upgrade issues
I am looking for some support during the process of upgrading istio from 1.17.x to 1.19.x in my AWS EKS cluster v1.25.
The steps I have performed so far to perform the Canary upgrade:

I checked upgrade notes and made sure all pre-requisites are met.
I deployed Control Plane to 1.19.7 (in parallel) following canary upgrade deployment.
I upgraded CNI to 1.19.7.
I upgraded Istio Gateways to 1.19.7.
I updated istioRev label on namespaces to use the new version: istio.io/rev: cp-1-19.

After performing all these steps, all new sidecar proxy injected into my namespaces are 1.19.7, however on istio-ingress namespace the version is still 1.17.3.. I did rollout restart of gateway deployment but with no changes.
kubectl get pods -n istio-ingress igw-core-5f5cqzert-abcd -oyaml | grep -i image:
    image: docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.17.3
    image: docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.17.3

Am I missing something ?
